# Web Scraping Census Data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, census

I am trying to web scrape data from the first table in the educational attainment section of the statistical atlas website that is based on census data. Essentially, I want to web scrape the percentages from the table and then add those percentages to a data frame that has zip codes at the very left and have separate columns for HS, no HS, and higher degree. I am trying to do this for all of the zip codes in NY City.

This is the code I have come up with so far can you help me refine it so that I can cycle through all of the zip codes and get a data frame with columns for each educational category from the first table with the zip codes in New York City?

Here is the link to statistical atlas: https://statisticalatlas.com/place/New-York/New-York/Overview

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import getpass
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen

file_name = 'C:/Users/Nicholas_G/Desktop/Google Drive/Work/Free 
Lance/Political Targeting/Census Data.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'NYC Zip Target'
Census_Data = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet_name)

zip_list = list(a for a in Census_Data['RESIDENTIAL_ZIP'])

url = "https://statisticalatlas.com/place/New-York/New-York/Overview"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
l = []

for a in zip_list:
   r = requests.get(f"https://statisticalatlas.com/zip/{a}/Educational- 
Attainment")
   s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
   data = s.find('svg', {'viewBox': '0 0 400 79'})
   value = data.find('svg', {'fill': '#000'})
   l.append(value)
```

Comment: What's the next thing you are stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: @Win One of the issues I’m having is that I’m unsure how to narrow the search criteria down to the percentages that are found in the tables themselves. Is there a way to specify in the find function multiple criteria such as the fill=#000? That could narrow it down but still take in other unnecessary text. So then my second question is there a way to specify that we are only looking for percents so that it doesn’t take in say HS diploma? I’m open to ideas, because so far what I’ve tried is based on too broad of a criteria.

Comment: So are you expecting only 3 values per zip code?

Comment: @QHarr yes and I want to have a column for each of them so no hs, hs, and higher degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that familiar with multiprocessing otherwise I would go down that route but here is my version using Session

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlMain = 'https://statisticalatlas.com/place/New-York/New-York/Overview'
urlAttainment = 'https://statisticalatlas.com/zip/{}/Educational-Attainment'

def getPercentages(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
        percentages = soup.select('[id="figure/educational-attainment"] rect title')
        percentages = [percentages[0].text,percentages[2].text,percentages[4].text]
        return percentages
    else:
        print(res.status_code, url)
        return []

def getCodes(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    codes = [code.text for code in soup.select('.info-table-contents-div a[href*=zip]')]
    return codes

results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    zipcodes = getCodes(urlMain)

    for zipcode in zipcodes:
        try:
            row = getPercentages(urlAttainment.format(zipcode))
            row.insert(0, zipcode)
            results.append(row)
        except IndexError as ex:
            print(ex,urlAttainment.format(zipcode))
df = pd.DataFrame(results,columns=['zipcode', 'HD', 'HS', 'NoHS'])
print(df)
```

Comment: I tried it and I got this traceback. I am going to look into this more, but can you investigate?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nicholas_G/PycharmProjects/Analysis/Political Targeting/Central Data Sources/Census_Scrapper.py", line 27, in <module>
    row = getPercentages(urlAttainment.format(zipcode))
  File "C:/Users/Nicholas_G/PycharmProjects/Analysis/Political Targeting/Central Data Sources/Census_Scrapper.py", line 12, in getPercentages
    percentages = [percentages[0].text,percentages[2].text,percentages[4].text]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I just discovered that some of the links are not there for some of the zip codes. So, that might be one of the reasons why.

Comment: I have updated answer. Here is a csv of results. https://filebin.net/uk61yc7004q7yk67

Comment: For the rest of the zipcodes I can apply a manual process directly from American factfnder

Comment: there are not too many missing and I guess you could write something to go and do that part too. I will probably revisit this and re-write for multiprocessing and test performance. I am fairly new to python so haven't read much about it yet. If I do I will ping you.